# Datime value showing null

Tags: flutter

I have a field in my cloud firestore and there is posted_date it's showing perfectly there but when i try to put it in Text(' ${word.date_posted}') it's showing null. Help me out:
[image: [This is my firestore]]

Here is an image of my database:

words_list.dart(This one calls the wordstile):

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kopala_dictionary/models/words.dart';
import 'package:kopala_dictionary/screens/home/words_tile.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class WordsList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WordsListState createState() => _WordsListState();
}

class _WordsListState extends State<WordsList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final words = Provider.of<List<Words>>(context) ?? [];

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: words.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return WordsTile(
          word: words[index],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


logged_home.dart(It displays all from words_tile and words_list):
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kopala_dictionary/main/about.dart';
import 'package:kopala_dictionary/models/words.dart';
import 'package:kopala_dictionary/screens/home/words_list.dart';
import 'package:kopala_dictionary/screens/wrapper.dart';
import 'package:kopala_dictionary/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:kopala_dictionary/services/database.dart';
import 'package:kopala_dictionary/shared/app_bar.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class LoggedInUserHome extends StatelessWidget {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<List<Words>>.value(
      value: DatabaseService().words,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[10],
        appBar: LoggedBar(),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(
                child: Text(
                  'Kopalationary Menu',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green[800],
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('Home'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Wrapper()));
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  'My profile',
                ),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('Logout'),
                onTap: () async {
                  dynamic result = await _auth.logoutUser();
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  'About',
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => About()),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: WordsList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

words_tile.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kopala_dictionary/models/words.dart';

class WordsTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Words word;
  WordsTile({this.word});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 8.0, 5.0, 0.0),
        child: ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.green[800],
            radius: 25.0,
          ),
          title: Text(word.word),
          subtitle: Text(' ${word.date_posted}'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It's showing null:
[image: [It's showing this]]

Comment: Kindly share the code when you are using `WordsTile`, it might be an issue with updating the state

Comment: OK, i have added all of the codes @AbdulrahmanFalyoun

Comment: In `body` you're calling `WordsList()` with no argument, the `WordsList` expecting you to provide a word as an aragument, as well it's out of stream provider

Comment: How can i do that help

Comment: hey try this word.date_posted.toString()

Comment: I tried but it's not working.